# How to define queryParams Angular 5 router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an issue with query params. Each router has a bit different queryParams.

$stateProvider allowed to define queryParams inside $state

```
.state('contacts.list', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
    url: '/test?test1&test2'
    data: {
        customData1: 44,
        customData2: "red"
    } 
  })
```

This code allows to get from queryParams only test1 and test2 fields.

About new Angular router, if I need watch queryParams, I should subscribe

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

});
```

This code has an issues, if I type in url some third party test3=lol, I will get this param in argument params and I don't want to filter it in all places

How can I set '/test?test1&test2' in Angular 5 router

Answer (score 1):

```
goProducts() {
  this.router.navigate(['/products'], { queryParams: { order: 'popular', 'price-range': 'not-cheap' } });
}
```

And the url will be like this.

http://localhost:4200/products?order=popular&price-range=not-cheap

In your component constructor

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

});
```

Hope this helps. Used [this](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/) to answer your question.

Comment: If I use this approach I will have case: 
User enters some third party param to url "test=lol" and press enter
My subscription will handle this change and I will get this unexpected param "test" in my handler

Comment: Then you have to send data to that componet without using query params.. If you need to hide data from the user you have to do this in another way.
Use a service to do this.